# Dump new array into .caffemodel file

Tags: caffe

I have a customized layer with certain parameters like kernel size,pad info etc.. among this I have array parameter which is of type bool/int. I need to add this array parameter in .caffemodel file after processing. How to link/Dump an array into caffemodel file?

I have included array parameter in .proto file like below.

```
{
 ... //other parameters
 repeated bool/int <varibale_name> [packed = true]
}
```

**Is it possible to create blob of type bool?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through py-caffe [net surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) -

```
net.params[learnable_layer_name].add_blob()
new_blob_index = len(net.params[learnable_layer_name]) - 1
net.params[learnable_layer_name][new_blob_index].reshape(desired_shape)
net.params[learnable_layer_name][new_blob_index].data[:] = new_data_to_insert
```

HTH.

Comment: Is there any other way to dumb array in caffemodel without using blob..??

Comment: Is it possible to create blob of type bool?

Comment: No, in the regular Caffe repository all blobs have the same data-type. You can however put ones / zeros and handle them however you wish in your code.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much